# How to make html, body cover the full screen even if when scrolling down

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I know some of you may not be surprised about this question.But seems like this situation I met is quite different. In this new project when I set `{ height: 100% }` or `{ min-height: 100% }` to `<html>` and `<body>`,they only cover the current visible zone.But when I scrolled down, they just didn't cover the belows.So how to solve this problem?

```
html
  min-height: 100%
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  @include Scroll
body
  min-height: 100%

@mixin Scroll
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track
    background-color: $trans-black
  ::-webkit-scrollbar
    width: 10px
    height: 10px
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
    border-radius: 5px
    background-color: $cyan
    background-clip: padding-box
    min-height: 28px
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover
    background-color: $h-cyan
```

[Style of other websites' html element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUx13.png)
[My html element style whose's height equals current broswer window height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZFKW.png)
Seems like other websites does well about this.How did they set the height equals all the content' height, not just current visible zone's height?

Comment: Setting the height: 100% only occupies the whole height of its parent prior to rendering. Can you give us just a glimpse of your current code?

Comment: @emaan14, don't ask for a glimpse (you'll get a screenshot). Sherr, please provide a [mcve]. Or any means to make your problem (and any potential solution) ***testable***. Read [ask] for tips on how to increase the question's chances of getting good/helpful answers.

Comment: Cool story, where is the code?

Comment: @emaan14 Thank you very much guys.Sorry for asking without details.I'm pretty new here.The previous comment is my code.I want html and body element to cover all the content in current page, not just current visible zone.Could you guys give me a little suggestions?Thanks

Comment: Thanks for supplying some, but please update your _question_ (not as a comment) with both the _HTML_ and the _CSS_ that means we can fully replicate your issue and help you get a resolution :)

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu Sorry for asking without details.I'm pretty new here.:P And I will learn to how to ask in a better way.I just updated the description with some code.Could you give me some help? Thank you very much,dude.

Comment: @EGC Sorry for that and I just updated it.Thanks for  reminding.:D

Comment: @SK Sorry for that...I'm pretty new here.I just updated the question with some code added.Could you gie me some help?

Comment: are you trying to do something like this https://www.artandscience.jp/ ?

Comment: @emaan14 I can't open this page...Could you tell me what did they do?